# How to use NDK with Android Studio to compile a Linux .so to Android .so platform

Tags: linux, android-ndk, shared-libraries, ndk-build

> I have installed Android Studio and would like to use Linux .so to
>   recompile and make it Android .so.

I have searched around and all examples show a ready make .c compile to .so and reuse that .so, in the Android Studio. This is not in my situation, I only have Linux .so without the .c file.

By referring from multiple websites, I made a JNI folder and put it along with gradle/build folder **OR** under app\src\main. It is **OR** because many developers put them at either location. I have no idea which is the correct version both the locations I have tried and it does not make any change to the project (no libs folder generated).

Some suggested that the Linux .so cannot be reused for Android .so because of platform difference, however, some also suggested it is possible without further explanation or example.

Would anyone here know how to do it?

Specifically:

> 1. Steps for creation of JNI folder and its location (I know how to create JNI folder, just not sure about the location)
> 2. How to call the .so and write codes to re-compile it? (Need
>      MainActivity or not, how does the code looks like)
> 3. ndk-build setup and the path/project settings

Thanks. Lee

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The people that told you that platform differences will prevent it were right.

Comment: Thank you. I have gave it up and look for other solution.